# ClassNotFound exception when adding custom filter to OpenStack

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

I am trying to create a custom filter for OpenStack, using their FilterScheduler component. The documentation for the FilterScheduler is here: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/nova/devref/filter_scheduler.html#

Now, there is not much in the way of documentation for creating your own custom filter. Infact, the complete documentation is:

```
If you want to create your own filter you just need to inherit from BaseHostFilter and implement one method: host_passes. This method should return True if host passes the filter. It takes host_state (describes host) and filter_properties dictionary as the parameters.

As an example, nova.conf could contain the following scheduler-related settings:

--scheduler_driver=nova.scheduler.FilterScheduler
--scheduler_available_filters=nova.scheduler.filters.standard_filters
--scheduler_available_filters=myfilter.MyFilter
--scheduler_default_filters=RamFilter,ComputeFilter,MyFilter
```

I have created a custom "test_filter.py" -- it is very similar to "all_hosts_filter.py", which is the simplest standard filter.

Here it is in it's entirety:

```
from nova.scheduler import filters
from nova.openstack.common import log as logging

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class TestFilter(filters.BaseHostFilter):
    """NOOP host filter. Returns all hosts."""

    def host_passes(self, host_state, filter_properties):
        LOG.debug("COMING FROM: nova/scheduler/filters/test_filter.py")
        return True
```

But when I put this file, "test_filter.py", in the `nova/scheduler/filters` folder and restart OpenStack I get the following exception:

```
CRITICAL nova [-] Class test_filter could not be found: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_filter'
```

It appears that OpenStack is registering and trying to import my new filter, but some error is occuring. For reference, this is what the releveant sections of my `/etc/nova/nova.conf` file looks like:

```
scheduler_available_filters=nova.scheduler.filters.all_filters
scheduler_available_filters=nova.scheduler.filters.test_filter.TestFilter
scheduler_default_filters=TestFilter,RamFilter,ComputeFilter
```

======

UPDATE: 15th April 2000 hours BST.

An update to this question, still struggling. After discussing the problem with boris-42 on the OpenStack IRC channel we have investigated a bit more:

Openstack-scheduler is run as service from /usr/bin/nova-scheduler

It then has an error:

```
"Inner Exception: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_filter' from (pid=32696) import_class /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/utils.py:78"
```

Which suggests it is using the /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/ folder for the source files of the installation.

Putting my custom "test_filter.py" into `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/scheduler/filters` causes the error above.

However, on closer inspection it appears that all other files in the  `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/scheduler/filters` folder are actually links to the files in  `/usr/share/pyshared/nova/scheduler/filters`

So I put my "test_filter.py" in  `/usr/share/pyshared/nova/scheduler/filters` -- and then created a symbolic link in the original folder.

This results in exactly the same folder. As long as the file is either present or a link exists in the folder  `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/scheduler/filters`  then the error occurs.

The nova.conf file has been updated as follows:

```
scheduler_available_filters=nova.scheduler.filters.TestFilter
scheduler_default_filters=TestFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you have to put your file in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/scheduler/filters`. You can put anywhere and make sure that path is in `PYTHONPATH`.

[As metnion in example](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/nova/devref/filter_scheduler.html#filtering)

If you want to create your own filter you just need to inherit from BaseHostFilter and implement one method: host_passes. This method should return True if host passes the filter. It takes host_state (describes host) and filter_properties dictionary as the parameters.

*As an example, nova.conf could contain the following scheduler-related settings:*

```
......
--scheduler_available_filters=myfilter.MyFilter
.......
```

You have to mention `myfilet.MyFilter` without `nova.scheduler.filters`.